# printf continuously printing

Tags: c, printf

Trying out another example from KandR, I have the following C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
  double nc = 5;

  printf("%*.0f",nc);

return 0;
}
```

This prints 5 and then it keeps moving (printing blank characters) from left to right and then a newline until stopped by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + C). When I change the `printf` line to `printf("%.0f",nc)` it works as expected i.e. it just prints 5 and stops.

According to http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/ printf's syntax is:

> %[flags][width][.precision][length] specifier.

I changed the `[width]` to `*` so that `printf` does not limit the digits in the output.

> 1) Why does it keep printing blank characters until stopped?
>
> 2) When I do not give any width, what does `printf` assume by default?
>
> 3) I also modified the above code to set `nc = 500`, then `printf`
>   does not print anything except the continuous blank characters!

When I change it to 500.00, it prints 500 and after that it keeps printing blank characters until stopped. Why is there no output when I set `nc=500` and why is there an output when I set `nc=500.00`?

Comment: The asterisk causes printf to read the width from an argument. Try `printf("%*.0f", 10, nc)`.

Answer (score 7):

The format specifier `"%*.0f"` expects two arguments: one is width specifier and the another is for double. Since you pass only one, it invokes *[undefined behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)*.

If you correct it, for example:

```
  printf("%*.0f",5, nc); // width 5
```

It'll work fine.